# How can I add a short path in the build path of Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have already a project in Eclipse, a old project. So everything is already set up, but i don't know how can i add a folder named third_party, which contains some specific jars.

My goal is not to change the librairies of a project, but just to add one thing to fix all my dependency's problems.

[image]

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't; you have to add JARs manually - but normally the "Add jars" dialog should allow you to select multiple JARs in one shot.

But what you can do is: define a project, that only contains your JAR files in the build path; and **export** all of them. Then you can make this project (maybe called "libraries" a pre-req for your other projects).

In other words: have one project that "collects" and exports all JARs that you need; then use that project in your other projects.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new User Library and add it to your project. that should take care of your dependency problem. You are not changing any libraries, but just adding the ones you need for the updates to the dependency issues.